# Turn Specific Observation and Row into Column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidy

I have data with rows and columns similar to the below example and want to basically convert every other row into a column. However, I also want to extract each specific observation and put that result into the corresponding column. So I would take:

```
       X1 x y xx xy           yy  
ci.lo1  0 0 0  0  0 -19350.63073
ci.up1  0 0 0  0  0    104.23538
ci.lo2  0 0 0  0  0  -8740.25544
ci.up2  0 0 0  0  0     52.97149
```

and trying to turn it into:

```
      X1.lo  X1.up x.lo x.up y.lo y.up xx.lo xx.up xy.lo xy.up        yy.lo     yy.up  
1   0            0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0 -19350.63073 104.23538
2   0            0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0  -8740.25544  52.97149
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do this type of conversion in `tidy`, if not in `base R` as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like something pivot_wider() could help with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
data %>% 
    rownames_to_column() %>% 
    mutate(rowname2=sub("^ci\\.(.*)\\d$","\\1",rowname), 
           rowname =sub("[^0-9]+","", rowname)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = rowname2, 
                values_from = -c(rowname2, rowname), 
                id_cols = rowname,
                names_sep = ".") %>%
    column_to_rownames()
  X1.lo X1.up x.lo x.up y.lo y.up xx.lo xx.up xy.lo xy.up      yy.lo     yy.up
1     0     0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0 -19350.631 104.23538
2     0     0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0  -8740.255  52.97149
```

Comment: I actually have a total of 702 rows of data. Running this code seems to do what i want, but creates another column `X1.lo1` after every 9 columns. Is it possible to stop it from creating a new column after 9 rows and go on for the entire dataframe?

Comment: This code does what you want for your example, sure. I would have to see your actual data to check the code against it.

Comment: You may add enough rows to your example until it creates that column `X1.lo1`, and update your expected output.

Comment: Your answer helped get me there, I added `mutate(rowname2 = gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', rowname2))` to remove the extra unnecessary digit in the `rowname2` column.